# php login with $_SESSION

Tags: php, html

i am making a login form with sessions this is my index.php page code:

```
<?php
    include "../config/MainClass.php";
    include "../connection.php";
    session_start();
    if (empty($_SESSION['admin'])){
        echo "<script>location='../login.php'</script>";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
        unset($_SESSION['admin']);
        echo "<script>location='../login.php'</script>";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['success'])) {
        if ($_GET['success']==1) {
            echo "<script>alert('Record Deleted Successfully');</script>";
        }
        
    }
    if (isset($_GET['success1'])) {
        if ($_GET['success1']==1) {
            echo "<script>alert('Record Updated Successfully');</script>";
        }
        
    }
?>
```

(thats the bit with the error)
and this is my login page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
    include "config/MainClass.php";
?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['SubBtn'])) {
    $to = $use->login($_POST['u'], $_POST['pw'], $_POST['em']);
    if ($to == 0) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">alert('Undefined user')</script>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; ./login.php">
    <?php } else {
        echo "<script>location='./dashboard/';</script>";
    }
} ?>


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/Login-Form-Dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="login-dark">
        <form method="POST">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="name" name="u" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="k" name="em" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="pw" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="SubBtn">Login</button></div><a class="forgot" href="signup.php">Dont have an account? Sign Up!</a></form>
    </div>
    <script src="asset/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the main class one is:

```
<?php
session_start([1]);

class MainClass
{
    function __construct()
    {

        
        $host_name = 'aaaaaaaaaaaa';
           $database = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
           $user_name = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa';
           $password = 'aaaaaaaaaa';


        
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;dbname=aaaaaaaaaaaa', $user_name, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }
        
    
    }

    function login($user, $pw, $em)
    {

        $to = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$user' AND password='$pw' AND email='$em' ");
        if ($to->rowCount() > 0) {
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $to->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

}



$use = new MainClass();
```

and it all works but when you login it redirects you to the index.php page but instantly redirects you back? it meant to only redirect you if your not logged in.

Anyone know how to fix this??

Comment: What is input type "k" on the E-Mail Field?

Comment: Are you sure you have `session_start()` in every file? If you do not include it, the script will not access the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: Having `session_start([1]);` at the top of your class file is super odd. IDK  what that will do to be honest, but Im certain it shouldnt be done that way. I would expect the script that _uses_ this class to start the session, not the class itself

Comment: Also, what is the `[1]` in `session_start([1]);` meant to do? Im not familiar with that usage

Comment: This code is probably susceptible to [sql injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/). You should use [prepared statements with parameter binding](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove `session_start();`  from index.php and in MainClass.php change it from `session_start([1]);` to simply `session_start();`

and also change `empty($_SESSION['admin'])` to `!isset($_SESSION['admin'])` in index.php

This way it worked for me (assuming the login() function was working correctly) and asigned a value to `admin` session

I also didn't check it with a database only with raw data but it shouldn't work much differently.

One last advice change `query()` to `prepare()` (prepared statements) in `MainClass` `login()` function. Passing data directly to the database without properly sanitazing it is extremly dangerous and will lead to SQL Injections.

Edit:

Do you mind copying and pasting once the edited code below ?
I've commented the changes I made.
Also make sure you are typing in correct login information

index.php

```php
<?php

include "../config/MainClass.php";
include "../connection.php";

if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {  // changed session name "admin" to "logged_in" as it makes more sense. 
    // And also now the session will hold only boolean (true/false) values, so it's easier to check

    echo "<script>location='./login.php'</script>"; // header("Location: login.php"); would also be an option 
    // die("reached here");  // For debugging
}
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
    echo "<script>location='./login.php'</script>";
    // die("reached here below"); // For debugging
}
if (isset($_GET['success'])) {
    if ($_GET['success'] == 1) {
        echo "<script>alert('Record Deleted Successfully');</script>";
    }
}
if (isset($_GET['success1'])) {
    if ($_GET['success1'] == 1) {
        echo "<script>alert('Record Updated Successfully');</script>";
    }
}
```

MainClass.php

```php
<?php
session_start();

class MainClass
{
    protected $db; // This was missing here since you used it below but it didn't exist in the class

    
    function __construct()
    {
        // Make sure to put your db connection details here 
        $hostName = 'localhost';
        $database = 'testDB';
        $userName = 'root';
        $password = '';



        try {
            // Don't hardcode your db connection details here like before. Instead type them in the variable above or you can even put them in a config file 
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $hostName . ';dbname=' . $database . '', $userName, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }
    }

    function login($user, $pw, $em)
    {

        // Used prepared statements instead of query() because it's more secure
        $to = $this->db->prepare("Select * from users where username=:user and password=:pw and email=:em");
        $to->bindParam(":user", $user);
        $to->bindParam(":pw", $pw);
        $to->bindParam(":em", $em);
        $to->execute(); // Execute the query above

        $rowNum = $to->rowCount();

        if ($rowNum) { // check if there are any results for your query
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; // assign a true value inside the "Logged_in" session
            return true;
        }

        return false; // Return false if something went wrong
    }
}



$use = new MainClass();
```

login.php

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
include "config/MainClass.php";

if (isset($_POST['SubBtn'])) {
    $to = $use->login($_POST['u'], $_POST['pw'], $_POST['em']);
    if ($to == 0) {
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Undefined user')
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; ./login.php">
<?php } else {
        echo "<script>location='./index.php';</script>";
    }
} ?>


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/Login-Form-Dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="login-dark">
        <form method="POST">
            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="name" name="u" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="k" name="em" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="pw" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="SubBtn">Login</button></div><a class="forgot" href="signup.php">Dont have an account? Sign Up!</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="asset/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="asset/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you change the `login` function to simply this:
`$_SESSION["admin"] = "test";
return true` and try again ? if it works that means the problem is within your login() function

Comment: hmm still doesnt work... it does redirect me but then instantly redirects me back

Comment: what was the edit you made? also could you say your discord if you have it so it says when you have a new message? or maybe try it your self in a codepen? or jsfiddle?

Comment: The the problem has got to be somewhere else. As it works perfectly on my environment. I even created a database to test it and everything looks fine.